# Why does numpy.save produce 100MB file for sys.getsizeof 0.33MB data?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `arr` (produced from multiple nested lists of mismatching lengths), which apparently takes only

```
sys.getsizeof(arr)/(1000*1000)
```

> 0.33848

MB of space in memory. However, when I attempt to save this data to disk with

```
myf=open('.\\test.npy', 'wb')
np.save(myf, arr)
myf.close()
```

the produced file `test.npy` turns out to be over 100MB large.

Why is that? Did I make some mistake with measuring the actual data size in python memory?
Or if not, is there some way to save the data more efficiently taking up only close to 0.33848MB space on the hard drive?

**EDIT:**

As requested in the comments, here some more properties of `arr`

```
arr.shape
```

> (14101, 6)

```
arr.dtype
```

> dtype('O')

```
arr.itemsize
```

> 4

```
arr.nbytes
```

> 338424

even though the dtype claims to be `dtype('O')`, the array only contains numerical values (integers and floats). Perhaps the object specification arises because of mismatching dimensions of nested lists?

Comment: Instead of using `getsizeof`, tell us about `arr`, specifically its `shape` and `dtype`.  That's all we/you need to know.  But I would expect `np.save` to match, provided the `dtype` is numeric or character.   `arr.itemsize` and `arr.nbytes` are also useful information.

Comment: I'm guessing the dtype is "object" since it was created from lists of different lengths. Can OP confirm the dtype of the array please?

Comment: @myrtlecat That's right, see edit of question. Is there a way to efficiently save nested lists of mismatching dimensions to binary file?

Comment: If the nested objects are themselves arrays, the sum total of their `nbytes` plus the main, should roughly match the `save`.  Memory use of lists is harder calculate, as is their pickle size.

Comment: That probably needs a new question, but there are a few options (depending on the level of nesting). If it's just one level (lists of different lengths) you could use `numpy.savez` which saves multiple arrays to the same file, or you could pad them with a nonsense value, or concatenate them and store the lengths separately. If the data is highly nested then npy format is not really designed for it. Other options would be JSON, or HDF5 maybe?

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed abbreviation of `MB` for megabytes  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte If you use `mb` it looks like millibits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array composed of several arrays:

```
In [98]: arr = np.array([np.ones(10), np.zeros((200,300)),np.arange(1000).reshape(100,10)],object)
```

Total memory use:

```
In [100]: sum([a.nbytes for a in arr]+[arr.nbytes])                                                  
Out[100]: 488104
```

Save it and check the file size

```
In [103]: np.save('test.npy', arr, allow_pickle=True)                                                
In [104]: ll test.npy                                                                                
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 488569 Jul  8 17:46 test.npy
```

That's close enough!

A npz archive takes about the same space:

```
In [106]: np.savez('test.npz', *arr)                                                                 
In [107]: ll test.npz                                                                                
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 488828 Jul  8 17:49 test.npz
```

But compressing helps significantly:

```
In [108]: np.savez_compressed('test.npz', *arr)                                                      
In [109]: ll test.npz                                                                                
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 2643 Jul  8 17:50 test.npz
```

I suspect it's so compressible because the largest array is all 0s.  With random values arrays of the same size, compression is only to 454909.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.save` uses `pickle` to store arrays that have the "object" dtype. From the [numpy format documentation](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0001-npy-format.html):

> If the dtype contains Python **objects** (i.e. dtype.hasobject is True), then the data is a Python **pickle** of the array

The size of a pickled python object is not the same as its size in memory, hence the discrepancy.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to efficiently save nested lists of mismatching dimensions (with numeric values only) to a binary file?