# Python: How to save lists of 2D numpy arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, list, numpy, save, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to save a list of numpy arrays to disk so I don't have to generate it each time as this takes a while. The list contains approx 230,000 numpy arrays, with each numpy array having dimensions of 7xlength where the length of each array can vary between ~200-800.

I have tried np.save but I get an error saying "could not broadcast input array from shape (7,158) into shape (7)" The length of the first array in the list is 158 so it is failing at the first list item. I have also tried np.savez and also first converting the list of arrays to a pure numpy array using np.asarray(listname), but I get the same error.

What is the best way to save this list of arrays to disk so I can load and use it on demand?

Comment: It's the `np.array(your_list)` action at the start of `save`.  Sometimes it makes an object dtype array, but if the first dimensions match that action produces your error.  `np.savez(filename, *yourlist)` should handle the save without first trying to make an array.

Comment: You can also save them to JSON format (and optionally compress).

Answer (score 6):

A list with arrays that differ in 2nd dimension:

```
In [118]: alist = [np.ones((2,3)), np.zeros((2,5)), np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)]
```

Your error:

```
In [119]: np.array(alist, dtype=object)                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-357020ce4a02> in <module>
----> 1 np.array(alist, dtype=object)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2)
```

Correct way of making a object array:

```
In [120]: arr = np.empty(3, object)                                                                  
In [121]: arr[:] = alist                                                                             
In [122]: arr                                                                                        
Out[122]: 
array([array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])], dtype=object)
```

`save` works:

```
In [123]: np.save('test.npy', arr)                                                                   
In [124]: ll test.npy                                                                                
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 708 Jul  8 20:13 test.npy
```

`savez` works, with almost the same net file size:

```
In [125]: np.savez('test.npz', *arr)                                                                 
In [126]: ll test.npz                                                                                
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 972 Jul  8 20:13 test.npz
```

[Why does numpy.save produce 100MB file for sys.getsizeof 0.33MB data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802591/why-does-numpy-save-produce-100mb-file-for-sys-getsizeof-0-33mb-data/62805720#62805720)  is an example where the arrays differ in the first dimension.

The basic point is the `np.save` writes an array; it tries to make a list input into array.  An array from arrays of differing size pushes the bounds of `numpy`.  The latest 1.19 version starts to warn us about this.

Answer (score 2):

*(I deleted this answer after seeing that a comment already mentions the use of `np.savez` with `*yourlist`, but am undeleting it in order to provide an example of how to read the data back in again.)*

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [np.zeros((3,3)), np.arange(5)]

np.savez("myfile.npz", *list1)

data = np.load("myfile.npz")

list2 = [data[k] for k in data]

print(list2)
```

gives:

```
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

Despite the somewhat dictionary-like syntax for extracting `list2` from `data`, `data.values()` is not supported -- although `data.items()` is valid, so you could also do:

```
list2 = [v for k, v in data.items()]
```

From experimentation, it appears that if you omit the `.npz` suffix on `np.savez` then it will be appended automatically, but if you omit the suffix on `np.load` then the file will not be found.