# ValueError: could not convert string to float, When loading a list of arrays with different shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a list of 2D arrays and they have different shapes. For example,(60,40) and (42,40).

A sample code for starting can be

```
y = []
y.extend([np.ones((60,40)),np.ones((42,40)),np.ones((60,40))])
```

---

I saved them using `np.savetxt(os.path.join("D:\A\code_testing\dataset",'mfccs.csv'),  y,fmt='%s',delimiter=",")` for later use.

However, a ValueError occurred when I tried to load them back.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\A\Pycodes\Dataset_prep(Watkins) 2.0.ipynb Cell 9 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 X_mfcc = np.loadtxt(os.path.join("D:\A\code_testing\dataset",'mfccs.csv'),  delimiter=",")

File e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py:1148, in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows, like)
   1143 # read data in chunks and fill it into an array via resize
   1144 # over-allocating and shrinking the array later may be faster but is
   1145 # probably not relevant compared to the cost of actually reading and
   1146 # converting the data
   1147 X = None
-> 1148 for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1149     if X is None:
   1150         X = np.array(x, dtype)

File e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py:999, in loadtxt.<locals>.read_data(chunk_size)
    995     raise ValueError("Wrong number of columns at line %d"
    996                      % line_num)
    998 # Convert each value according to its column and store
--> 999 items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1001 # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting
   1002 items = pack_items(items, packing)

File e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py:999, in <listcomp>(.0)
    995     raise ValueError("Wrong number of columns at line %d"
...
    734 if '0x' in x:
    735     return float.fromhex(x)
--> 736 return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[-4.4259256e+02  4.0493172e+01  2.5947336e+01 ...  3.9495504e+00'
```

---

So i later tried using method([Python: How to save lists of 2D numpy arrays of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805566/python-how-to-save-lists-of-2d-numpy-arrays-of-different-lengths))

```
np.savez("D:\A\code_testing\dataset\mfcc.npz",y)
data = np.load("D:\A\code_testing\dataset\mfcc.npz")
list2 = list2 = [v for k, v in data.items()]
print(len(list2))
```

I got error `ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False`

Comment: So, what exactly is `y`?  It can't be a list of 2D arrays, because `savetxt` doesn't work on that.  Couldn't you save each array to a separate csv file?  Saving arrays of different sizes to a single CSV file is never going to work reliably.  How could it tell where one ends and another starts?

Comment: Show a sample of the saved file.

Comment: @hpaulj Hi hpauji, I have added a sample code for starting. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I want to see a sample of the file, not the code that creates it.  Did you look at it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do these separately.  Again, ASSUMING `y` really is a Python list of numpy arrays:

```
for i,a in enumerate(y):
    name = 'mfccs%02d.csv' % i
    np.savetxt( name, a, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')

...

y = [np.loadtxt(name, delimiter=',') for name in glob.glob('mfcc*.csv')]
```

Comment: I am creating a dataset that contains time series features extracted from audio files. Saving one by one may be a little troublesome as there are thousands NumPy arrays. Is there a way for me to save them into a single file? By the way, i  have edited the question, adding a sample code for starting. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it doesn't have to be a `CSV` file, anything that can help me save and load the list of arrays will work.

Comment: You might checkout the `h5py` module.  HDF files are a common way to store non-homogenous data sets in data science.

Comment: The problem is solved as a * is needed when I run np.savez

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put a `*` before the list when doing the saving

`np.savez("D:\A\code_testing\dataset\mfcc.npz",*y)`